# Compiler showing warning during compilation of the following code

Tags: c++, c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
  char str[6][50] ;    // a 2d character array
  int  i ;
  for(i = 0 ; i < 6 ; i++)
  {
    scanf("%s",(str+i)) ; // in here the warning was shown
  }
  return 0 ;
}`
```

During Output :- 
scanf() is showing warning on compilation - warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char (*)[50]’ [-Wformat=]

Comment: As per the comment, str is a 2d array.  The scanf function expects a 1d array but instead gets this.

What is your question?

Comment: What's not clear about warning? Use `scanf("%s",*(str+i));` or `scanf("%s",str[i]);`.

Comment: I bet the problem is that scanf expects type `char*` but that the argument is of type `char(*)[50]`.

Answer (score 3):

Remember that arrays naturally decays to pointers to their first element? That means `str` by itself is treated as a *pointer*. With `str + i` you are doing pointer arithmetic, the result of which is another pointer (to the i:th element in this case). The type of that pointer is a pointer to an array, `char (*)[50]`, it's not the array itself.

What you need to do is to *dereference* the pointer: `*(str + i)`. Or as it's the same, `str[i]`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to access each element of str in turn.  To do this use `scanf("%s",str[i]);` (as per usr's comment).